# Why do build configuration not run in parallel for a build chain in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, build-chain

All documentation on build chains on the TeamCity and also their blog postings deals with simples setup that don't expose the more complex setups that you may encounter in real life which brings me to the following question.

I have the need for a few more complex setups:

`A--\ /--D--\
    C       F
B--/ \--E--/`

Ideally A & B and D & E would run concurrently on different build nodes.

`A--\C/--E
B--/D\--F`

In the above A & B run concurrent, as do C & D but C & D are only triggered if both A & B pass, the same goes for E & F they run concurrent, but only if both C & D pass.

  `/-- B --\
A          D
  \-- C --/`

Ideally B & C should run in parallel on different nodes.

However TeamCity refuses to do this and all builds are un sequentially on a single build node which is highly annoying because it blows build times out of the water.

I've tried various combinations of Snapshot dependencies and Finish build trigger to no avail, TeamCity refuses to run any steps parallel.

Comment: That's unexpected. Have you perhaps set up agent requirements so that these are all stuck on one agent?

Comment: No agent requirements are present for the builds, except that they need to have Xcode installed.

Comment: Do you have at least 2 build agents (nodes) attached to the server? And these nodes are compatible with both of your parallel build configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapshot dependencies in TC 10.x work slightly different between templates and build configurations.

Given this example config, where the build is triggered on D will result in 2 different execution trees.

  `/-- B --\
A          D
  \-- C --/`

If the snapshot dependencies are defined on the templates then TeamCity will execute all builds sequentially, eg. A, B, C & D.

If the snapshot dependencies are defined on the build configuration then TeamCity will execute the builds as A, then B & C in parallel and finally D.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all "Finished build" triggers. They are not needed to run snapshot dependencies chain. Just start a build in last configuration of chain (F or D) and all other builds will be added to queue according to re-use configuration.

Comment: I am well familiar with the snapshot dependency and how its used to create a build chain. So let's take my last example where A -> B & C -> D, both B & C depend on running A, how do I prevent TC from queuing up B & C sequentially and instead run those in parallel?

And how do I start a last build in a chain if there are 2 'last' builds? like in my middle example?

Comment: For the case of `A -> B & C -> D`. As long as there are four snapshot dependencies and **no** finished build triggers, starting `D` should queue `A`, `B` and `C`, with `B` and `C` executing in parallel after `A` is finished (as long as compatible build agent is available).
If TeamCity behaves otherwise, it is a bug